# Woocommerce: How to customize product category widgets to show selected categories?

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to customize the product category widgets to show only selected product categories.

I managed to get some codes here which can disable certain product categories in all product category widgets.  However, what I wanted to do is to have a few product category widgets and to select the product categories in each of the widget.

I have tried but it doesn't work unfortunately...
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-category-selection-widget/

This is what I found which can disable certain product categories in all product category widgets

```
/**
 * Remove Categories from WooCommerce Product Category Widget
 *
 * @author   Ren Ventura
 */

//* Used when the widget is displayed as a dropdown
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_dropdown_args', 'rv_exclude_wc_widget_categories' );
//* Used when the widget is displayed as a list
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'rv_exclude_wc_widget_categories' );
function rv_exclude_wc_widget_categories( $cat_args ) {
    $cat_args['exclude'] = array('55','68'); // Insert the product category IDs you wish to exclude
    return $cat_args;
}
```

Comment: Please, add your code that disable certain product categories in your question.Always add your related code in the question.

Comment: Added the code.  Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Sorry your question is really unclear Can you be more explicit giving some detailled examples.

Comment: Comments are not really the way … Please "Edit" your question and try to make that readable, visual, understandable and sexy, taking care of your wording and using fake names like "Apple", "Pear" (instead of A, B, C, D, E). This way you will get better chances to get a useful answer. Now you can't have 2 different widgets on the same page, as the available filters works for all widget of the same kind…